# Official twitter widget fails in Wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, twitter, widget

**I started blogging on free wordpress platform** and I wanted to add [official twitter widget](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/) to my blog.

I add following code as text widget to blog's side bar in twenty fourteen theme.

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Menuka_cs3" data-widget-id="695529194466504704">Tweets by @Menuka_cs3</a>
<script>
    ! function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

but it look like this

[image]

what I was able to detect when I save the widget it lost it's `<script>` tags so it just show the content letters. Here is what I get when I save the widget

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Menuka_cs3">Tweets by @Menuka_cs3</a> !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Why not just use Wordpress's own Twitter widget?

Comment: is it a plugin?
I can't use plugins in wordpress blog.
Can you give me the link please.
I'm new to wordpress

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+twitter+timeline+widget)

Comment: Well it worked.
Thanks.
But I still wonder what is the reason that <script> tags missing

Comment: You can't use html tags like <script> in text widget. Text widget is only for showing some text. Use a twitter plugin instead

Comment: I can't agree with that Ajith. I've done the same process before. They works just fine. You can see one time here where it worked. http://www.gavel.cmb.ac.lk/ As you can see this twitter text widget work fine

Comment: Works fine when I tried to add it to twentyfourteen in the text widget. Do you have `Automatically add paragraphs` checked? Be sure that's not checked...

Comment: Yeah It's not checked

Comment: Do you try to abusing widget text in free blog of wordpress.com with javascript?

Comment: what? :O
I just wanted to add the Twitter widget

Comment: @Menuka Ishan No problem sir. I do like you do when first time blogging. :) btw I update my answer if you need to embed Twitter timeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to add code javasript in [text widget](https://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/text-widget/) of **WordPress.com** blogs. You can't.

> Users are not allowed to post JavaScript on WordPress.com blogs.
>   JavaScript can be used for malicious purposes. As an example,
>   JavaScript has taken sites such as MySpace.com and LiveJournal offline
>   in the past. The security of all WordPress.com blogs is a top priority
>   for us, and until we can guarantee scripting languages will not be
>   harmful, they will not be permitted.
>
> JavaScript from trusted partners, such as YouTube and Google Video, is
>   converted into a WordPress shortcode when a post is saved.

https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/#javascript

But if you are in [WordPress.com VIP](https://vip.wordpress.com/), and need to embed your Twitter timeline, you could follow this post [How To Embed a Twitter Timeline Widget](https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/how-to-embed-a-twitter-timeline-widget/).

Comment: I think this is the reason

Answer (score 1):

When Wordpress saves the content, it filters it because it thinks its text, not code. One **possible** solution is to create a shortcode like this:

Open you theme/functions.php file and paste this at the end

```
function twitter_shortcode( $atts) {
    $twitter = '<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Menuka_cs3" data-widget-id="695529194466504704">Tweets by @Menuka_cs3</a>
<script>
    ! function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
    </script>';
    return $twitter;
}
add_shortcode( 'twitter', 'twitter_shortcode' );
```

Then, on your post you call the shortcode:

```
[twitter]
```

Please note that this function is completely **untested** but was taken from the official wordpress page at:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: I believe that I mentioned "i started blogging on free wordpress platform" in the question. As far as I know I can't edit pages in wordpress site right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Menuka_cs3" data-widget-id="710522346977824769">tweets by @Menuka_cs3</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```